# CKAN - choroplethmap

Tags: python, ckan, opendata

I have correctly installed CKAN 2.5 version with some plugins and it is running in a production server. Now I wanted to add [ckanext-mapviews'](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-mapviews) extension to configure regular choropleth maps to CKAN.

I have followed the instructions as it is said installing the setup.py and adding **choroplethmap** to the list in **ckan.plugins** attribute but I don't see the new **Choropleth Map** chart type option in the view type's list. I have also checked logs but there is no clue to know what it could be happening.

Does anyone know what can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I am answering myself about the problem I had found explaning some kind of a workaround for the Choropleth Map:

- Column names in the spreadheet can not have "special chars" (accents or some other char).
- I only get working the map width a XLS (not CSV) file.

I hope it should be useful for anyone that has this problem.